# java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I was in the process of changing an Activity into a Fragment and got the following error as soon as I inflated the RecyclerView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
          ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ----> View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_containing_recyclerview, 
                    container, false);
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager

Before I changed my Activity to a Fragment the inflate went just fine.

Some further research showed that *removing all my child elements* from the recyclerview layout helped solve the problem. However I do not understand why that would change anything and why it did work work with an activity before.

**WORKS**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"   
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >    

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"   
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >    


<View
    android:id="@+id/randomview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: removing the view works, but it's not the solution to the entire problem because we sometimes really need the views we put there

Answer (score 50):

This question is quite old but for the benefit of people still facing this issue I thought I would leave an answer. I am just learning Android development and this issue was frustrating. Later on I found out that you are not supposed to add any views or view groups under `RecyclerView`. The layout that you want to appear under the `RecyclerView` needs to be defined separately in an independent resource file.

Then in the adapter implementation (the one that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<>`, in the overridden method `public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` when you inflate the layout for the view (this is inflating the layout for each item of the recycler view), you can specify the above separate layout that you created. Android then inflates this layout for every item that needs to be added to the recycler view.

[This article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) helped me see this clearly.

Answer (score 3):

`RecyclerView` is a `ViewGroup` that requires `LayoutManager` that will do the layouting of its children. In your case `RecyclerView` needs the child view to be passed to the `LayoutManager`, but I'm not sure if it is possible to pass xml reference of View to `LayoutManager`.

Comment: nope, it is not possible to pass items to RV directly. You have to use an adapter and a layout manager.

Comment: this was my issue, I had accidentally put a view inside of my recycler view. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue when I tried to use [android-parallax-recycleview](https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview).

The solution was simple, you can create the layout manager manager manually.

Code snippet from [example-parallaxrecycler](https://github.com/kanytu/example-parallaxrecycler/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/poliveira/apps/exampleparallaxrecycler/MainActivity.java#L24):

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
myRecycler.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Comment: And where does `myRecycler` come from?  At least in my code it comes from `myRecycler = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);`, and `v` comes from `inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_recycler_view, container, false)`, which is the line with the error.  How does placing code after the exception prevent the exception from occuring?

Comment: `mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view);`

Comment: What @MohammadWalid probably means is that EVERY `ReclyclerView` needs a `LayoutManager`. Even though it might appear that your app crashes while inflating a layout that actually does have a `LayoutManager`, it's not unprobable that it crashes on a different `RecylerView`. I am seeing this behaviour and it costed me a few hours :-) This answer seems incomplete though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just inflating the views afterwards like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalog_viewer, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.catalog_child, container);        
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Still null pointer exception even if I initialize it in `onCreateView`.

Add it programatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <!-- <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPromotions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />  -->

</LinearLayout>


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...
    // create recyclerview
...
            LinearLayout llContainer = (LinearLayout)  v.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
            llContainer.addView(recyclerView);

            return v;
        }
```