# Xml Scrollview is not working

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have tried every possible way of Scrolling this xml attributes but its not working at all. Please provide me the way to use it and my parent layout drawer layout.
Thank You

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/hmebar"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
                <!--<include layout="@layout/home_screen"/>-->

                <include layout="@layout/banner" />

                <include layout="@layout/featured_products" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: this is the example for scrollview  http://javatechig.com/android/android-scrollview-example

Comment: Do you have another scrolling View - e.g. a ListView - in any of the included layouts?

Comment: ScrollView is enabled only if your layout exceeds the screen size

Comment: yes i have recycler view in the featured products layout @MikeM.

Comment: I believe that's your problem. ScrollViews don't play nice with nested scrolling Views. Use a [`NestedScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

Comment: i will try it and give feedback to u

Comment: @AkshayBhat i had tried that too its not working

Comment: @MikeM.its not working

Answer (score 0):

Custom your scrollView as:

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public MyScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i("MyScrollView", "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false" );
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.i("MyScrollView", "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false");
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i("MyScrollView", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false" );
                return false;

            default: Log.i("MyScrollView", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action ); break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        Log.i("MyScrollView", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction() );
        return true;
    }
}
```

Using it in your layout.

Comment: no sir its not working in one of the include there is recycler view

Comment: Could you change `public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView ` to `public class MyRecycleView extends RecycleView` and replace it to RecycleView on include layout ?

Comment: The problem is overide `onInterceptTouchEvent` function to it disable scrollview touch when recycleview is touched.

Comment: <com.app.prominere.souqalkhaleejia.MyRecycleView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

Comment: i had changed it like this

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.prominere.souqalkhaleejia/com.app.prominere.souqalkhaleejia.Homescreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager

Comment: at com.app.prominere.souqalkhaleejia.Homescreen.onCreate(Homescreen.java:55)

Comment: Can you share me onCreate() function, where you using RecycleView ?

Comment: featuredproduct = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.featuredproduct);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        featuredproduct.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        featuredAdapter = new FeaturedAdapter(getApplicationContext(),Featurelst);
        featuredproduct.setAdapter(featuredAdapter);

Comment: Try add `featuredproduct .setHasFixedSize(true);` after the first line

Comment: did you have childview on RecycleView layout as emptyview ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563853/java-lang-illegalstateexception-recyclerview-has-no-layoutmanager-in-fragment

Comment: <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/namefeatured" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/featuredproduct"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: this the recyclerview xml sir